# Can i use VTK+Qt for creating my Android applications?

Tags: android, qt, vtk

I'm a newbie at android application development and not good at English.

---

I want to create medical image processing application on android.  I have searched for how to use [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) (it's a cross-platfrom image processing library that I use in java) and found that you can use QT with android.  My Question:  "Can I use VTK+Qt for creating my Android applications?"; and if so, where do I start?

Thanking you for assistance in advance.

Comment: Qt and android do not work together out of the box : there is some work involved to have it work properly (you can check Qt lighthouse for details). If your framework is in java, why not keep all your application in java ?

Comment: Yes, my framework is in java application.but i don't know what kind of tools or library that can use image processing on mobile(i want to show DICOM file on mobile)    Thank you for answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot currently use VTK with Android - there is a significant amount of porting to be done. VTK has a desktop OpenGL 1.x implementation, but no OpenGL ES implementation as would be required for mobile platforms. Some early work is starting in this area, but it does mean even if you get Qt working VTK will not be able to render on this device.

Comment: Oh,it's bad news.I cannot use VTK with Android :( OK. I will search for new library that can use image processing on Android. Now,t found JJIL Library(http://code.google.com/p/jjil/). Please advise me.  Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with that library. Android (general mobile support) is something that will come, but it is not available in VTK right now.

Comment: Umm,you can tall me what is vtk 5.6.1 implementation OpenGL version ? Thanks again

Comment: It is not clear what you mean, VTK uses OpenGL 1.1, and then optionally several OpenGL extensions if available (probed at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [VES](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VES)? 
VES is the VTK OpenGL ES Rendering Toolkit. It is a C++ rendering library for mobile devices using OpenGL ES 2.0. VES integrates with the Visualization Toolkit (VTK) to deliver scientific and medical visualization capabilities to mobile application developers.

Answer (score 1):

A first VTK port attempt for Android platforms was done by Ethan Rublee on December 2010. The code is still available on his git repository here: https://github.com/ethanrublee